# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2014 using java 8 (zulu 8u332)

Tags: sql-server, ssl, java-8, tls1.2, tls1.3

My application is connected to ***MSSQL Server 2014*** and is developed using ***Java 8***(zulu 8u332-8.62.0.19).
The database do not have SSL enabled.

The following error appears: `The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]".`

for me, to enable TLS12 on database in not a possible solution; neither to enable TLS10 into my application;

Comment: Why can't you add TLS1.2 to SQL Server? SQL server 2014 had TLS 1.2 Support added in [KB3135244](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe), and was supported on SP1 CU5 or RTM CU12 onwards, and was released way back in 2016; have you not updated your server yet? TLS1.0 is *long* unsupported now.

Comment: You need to install the relevant KB as linked above (preferably the latest build instead https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2014/01/sql-server-2014-versions.html) also you need to install relevant operating system updates for TLS 1.2 if you are on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: I can not  make changes on db side. I have to find a workaround. What I see so far is that there is an incompatibility between MSSQL 2014 and java8-332.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to include the connector jar file in your library, `mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar` works well with java 8, then if your sql server doesn't have a password you can use this code

```
public Connection getConnection() {
           Connection conn = null;
           try{
               Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
               if(conn==null)  conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://your_server_name; databaseName=name_of_the_database_you_use;integratedSecurity=true;" +
                       "trustServerCertificate=true;IntegratedSecurity=true;");
          
               }


            catch (Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();

           }
        return conn;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have already tried to change the jdbc version but it does not work.
About passing the parameters via URL, it also does not change the behavior.